# iOS indexPath is nil (custom accessory image)

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, nsindexpath, accessoryview

I've used the sample code from Apple for "Accessory" to have a custom accessory image in my table. The table renders the image properly and everything but when I click on the image that is supposed to take me to the **accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath** method nothing happens because indexPath is nil for some reason. See this method which checks the indexPath:

```
- (void)accessoryButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just use `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` in your `UITableViewDelegate`?

Comment: I need to use this method so I can use custom accessory image (as seen in the Sample Code for "Accessory" from Apple). Although in that sample code Apple uses UITableViewController as parent class which has a tableView ivar. And I'm using UIViewController class which has no tableView ivar. Can I just create the tableView ivar for my UIViewController class then?

Comment: Yeah, If you create the table in Interface Builder, make an IBOutlet. If you create it in your code, just declare the ivar in your header file.